# what is the reason of increasing image size in rotation?

Tags: c#, image, rotation, image-resizing

I have a c# application that contains an image gallery where I display some pictures.
This gallery have some features including left and right rotation.
everything is perfect but when I choose a picture from gallery and press rotation button (regardless left or right rotation), size of the picture increase significantly.
It should be mentioned that the picture's format is JPEG.

Size of picture before rotation : 278 kb

Size of picture after rotation : 780 kb

My code for rotation is like bellow :

```
 public Image apply(Image img)
    {  
        Image im = img;
        if (rotate == 1) im.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
        if (rotate == 2) im.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
        if (rotate == 3) im.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);

        //file size is increasing after RotateFlip method

        if (brigh != DEFAULT_BRIGH ||
            contr != DEFAULT_CONTR ||
            gamma != DEFAULT_GAMMA)
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(im))
            {
                float b = _brigh;
                float c = _contr;
                ImageAttributes derp = new ImageAttributes();
                derp.SetColorMatrix(new ColorMatrix(new float[][]{
                        new float[]{c, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        new float[]{0, c, 0, 0, 0},
                        new float[]{0, 0, c, 0, 0},
                        new float[]{0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                        new float[]{b, b, b, 0, 1}}));
                derp.SetGamma(_gamma);
                g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, img.Size),
                    0, 0, img.Width, img.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, derp);
            }
        }
        return im; 
    }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: JPEG compression / quantization table? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324790

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case applying `RotateFlip` on `im` is changing the `ImageFormat` from `Jpeg` to `MemoryBmp`.
By Default when you save the image it is going to make use of the default `ImageFormat`. This will be the format returned by `im.RawFormat`

if you check the GUID `im.RawFormat.Guid`

*Before RotateFlip*

{b96b3cae-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e}
which is same as `ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid`

*After RotateFlip*

{b96b3caa-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e}
which is same as `ImageFormat.MemoryBmp.Guid`

At the time of saving the image pass the `ImageFormat` as the second parameter which will ensure that it uses the correct format. If not mentioned it is going to be the one in `im.RawFormat`

So If you want to save as jpeg at the time of saving call

```
im.Save("filename.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

This time the file size should be less than the original size.

Also note `ImageFormat` is in `System.Drawing.Imaging` namespace

**NOTE**

To control the quality of the jpeg make use of the overloaded Save method as mentioned in this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80.aspx)

---

**EDIT Based On Comment**

OK assuming you are using SQL Server you must be having a `image` datatype column (it is recommended to use `varbinary(max)` instead of `image` as in future it is going to be obselete ([Read MSDN Post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191262%28SQL.105%29.aspx))

***Now to the steps***

```
1) read the contents as a stream / byte[] array

2) convert this to Image

3) perform rotate operation on the Image

4) convert this Image back to stream / byte[] array

5) Update the database column with the new value
```

Comment: @Joey not really; looks identical. but have a closer look at the first part of the GUIDs it is b96b3cae vs b96b3caa

Comment: @masoudramezani you are welcome; if it answered your question you can mark it as the answer

Comment: @prashanth t: I have an image and after rotating I want to save rotated image on itself. image is loaded from db. what is your solution?

Comment: Is your image saved in disk and the path is in the DB or is the image itself is directly saved in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons:

1. The JPEG compression/encoding/sampling is not optimized as the original JPEG.
2. JPEG is not transparent. When an image is not rotated 90/180/270 degrees, the rectangular boundary of the image becomes larger.

Comment: The second point has nothing to do with transparency. PNG images would need to be enlarged too in that case.

Comment: Theoretically transparent background doesn't need same amount of storage as picture content. That's why I mentioned transparency.

Comment: JPEG compresses *very* differently from PNG. Those two are not at all comparable in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

You should to keep raw `ImageFormat` before change the image, and save to file by raw image format. Like bellow code :

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(filePath))
{
    var rawFormat = image.RawFormat;
    image.RotateFlip(angel);
    image.Save(filePath, rawFormat);
}
```